# Find intersection of values in dictionary under a same key - python

Tags: python, dictionary, key, reduce, functools

I have a file with lines, each line is split on "|", I want to compare arguments 5 from each line and if intersect, then proceed. This gets to a second part:

- first arguments1,2 are compared by dictionary, and if they are same AND
- if arguments5,6 are overlapping,
  then those lines get concatenated.

How to compare intersection of values under the same key? The code below works cross-key but not within same key:

```
from functools import reduce 
reduce(set.intersection, (set(val) for val in query_dict.values()))
```

Here is an example of lines:
text1|text2|text3|text4 text 5| text 6| text 7 text 8|
text1|text2|text12|text4 text 5| text 6| text 7|
text9|text10|text3|text4 text 5| text 11| text 12 text 8|

The output should be:
text1|text2|text3;text12|text4;text5;text4;text5|text6;text7 text8;text6

In other words, only those lines that are matching by 1st,2nd arguments (cells equal) and if 5th,6th arguments are overlapping (intersection) are concatenated.

Here is input file:

```
Angela Darvill|19036321|School of Nursing, University of Salford, Peel House Eccles, Manchester M30 0NN, UK.|['GB','US']|['Salford', 'Eccles', 'Manchester']
Helen Stanley|19036320|Senior Lecturer, Institute of Nursing and Midwifery, University of Brighton, Westlain House, Village Way, Falmer, BN1 9PH Brighton, UK.|['US']|['Brighton', 'Brighton']
Angela Darvill|190323121|School of Nursing, University of Salford, Peel House Eccles, Manchester M30 0NN, UK.|['US']|['Brighton', 'Eccles', 'Manchester']
Helen Stanley|19576876320|Senior Lecturer, Institute of Nursing and Midwifery, University of Brighton, Westlain House, Village Way, Falmer, BN1 9PH Brighton, UK.|['US']|['Brighton', 'Brighton']
```

The output should look like:

```
Angela Darvill|19036321;190323121|...
Helen Stanley|19036320;19576876320|...
```

Angela Darvill gets stacked because two records share same name, same country and same city(-ies).

Comment: Can you provide an example of inputs and outputs ? And what do you mean by "intersect" for "arguments" ?

Comment: @Lenormju see updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your improved question :

```py
import itertools


data = """\
Angela Darvill|19036321|School of Nursing, University of Salford, Peel House Eccles, Manchester M30 0NN, UK.|['GB','US']|['Salford', 'Eccles', 'Manchester']
Helen Stanley|19036320|Senior Lecturer, Institute of Nursing and Midwifery, University of Brighton, Westlain House, Village Way, Falmer, BN1 9PH Brighton, UK.|['US']|['Brighton', 'Brighton']
Angela Darvill|190323121|School of Nursing, University of Salford, Peel House Eccles, Manchester M30 0NN, UK.|['US']|['Brighton', 'Eccles', 'Manchester']
Helen Stanley|19576876320|Senior Lecturer, Institute of Nursing and Midwifery, University of Brighton, Westlain House, Village Way, Falmer, BN1 9PH Brighton, UK.|['US']|['Brighton', 'Brighton']
"""

lines = tuple(tuple(line.split('|')) for line in data.splitlines())

results = []
for line_a_index, line_a in enumerate(lines):
    # we want to compare each line with each other, so we start at index+1
    for line_b_index, line_b in enumerate(lines[line_a_index+1:], start=line_a_index+1):
        assert len(line_a) >= 5, f"not enough cells ({len(line_a)}) in line {line_a_index}"
        assert len(line_b) >= 5, f"not enough cells ({len(line_b)}) in line {line_b_index}"
        assert all(isinstance(cell, str) for cell in line_a)
        assert all(isinstance(cell, str) for cell in line_b)

        columns0_are_equal = line_a[0] == line_b[0]
        columns1_are_equal = line_a[1] == line_b[1]
        columns3_are_overlap = set(line_a[3]).issubset(set(line_b[3])) or set(line_b[3]).issubset(set(line_a[3]))
        columns4_are_overlap = set(line_a[4]).issubset(set(line_b[4])) or set(line_b[4]).issubset(set(line_a[4]))
        print(f"between lines index={line_a_index} and index={line_b_index}, {columns0_are_equal=} {columns1_are_equal=} {columns3_are_overlap=} {columns4_are_overlap=}")
        if (
            columns0_are_equal
            # and columns1_are_equal
            and (columns3_are_overlap or columns4_are_overlap)
        ):
            print("MATCH!")
            results.append(
                (line_a_index, line_b_index,) + tuple(
                    ((cell_a or "") + (";" if (cell_a or cell_b) else "") + (cell_b or "")) if cell_a != cell_b
                    else cell_a
                    for cell_a, cell_b in itertools.zip_longest(line_a, line_b)
                )
            )

print("Fancy output :")
lines_to_display = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable((lines[result[0]], lines[result[1]], result[2:]) for result in results))
columns_widths = (max(len(str(index)) for result in results for index in (result[0], result[1])),) + tuple(
    max(len(cell) for cell in column)
    for column in zip(*lines_to_display)
)

for width in columns_widths:
    print("-" * width, end="|")
print("")

for result in results:
    for line_index, original_line in zip((result[0], result[1]), (lines[result[0]], lines[result[1]])):
        for column_index, cell in zip(itertools.count(), (str(line_index),) + original_line):
            if cell:
                print(cell.ljust(columns_widths[column_index]), end='|')
        print("", end='\n')  # explicit newline
    for column_index, cell in zip(itertools.count(), ("=",) + result[2:]):
        if cell:
            print(cell.ljust(columns_widths[column_index]), end='|')
    print("", end='\n')  # explicit newline

for width in columns_widths:
    print("-" * width, end="|")
print("")

expected_outputs = """\
Angela Darvill|19036321;190323121|...
Helen Stanley|19036320;19576876320|...
""".splitlines()

for result, expected_output in itertools.zip_longest(results, expected_outputs):
    actual_output = "|".join(result[2:])
    assert actual_output.startswith(expected_output[:-3])  # minus the "..."
```

```
-|--------------|--------------------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
0|Angela Darvill|19036321            |School of Nursing, University of Salford, Peel House Eccles, Manchester M30 0NN, UK.                                                   |['GB','US']       |['Salford', 'Eccles', 'Manchester']                                     |
2|Angela Darvill|190323121           |School of Nursing, University of Salford, Peel House Eccles, Manchester M30 0NN, UK.                                                   |['US']            |['Brighton', 'Eccles', 'Manchester']                                    |
=|Angela Darvill|19036321;190323121  |School of Nursing, University of Salford, Peel House Eccles, Manchester M30 0NN, UK.                                                   |['GB','US'];['US']|['Salford', 'Eccles', 'Manchester'];['Brighton', 'Eccles', 'Manchester']|
1|Helen Stanley |19036320            |Senior Lecturer, Institute of Nursing and Midwifery, University of Brighton, Westlain House, Village Way, Falmer, BN1 9PH Brighton, UK.|['US']            |['Brighton', 'Brighton']                                                |
3|Helen Stanley |19576876320         |Senior Lecturer, Institute of Nursing and Midwifery, University of Brighton, Westlain House, Village Way, Falmer, BN1 9PH Brighton, UK.|['US']            |['Brighton', 'Brighton']                                                |
=|Helen Stanley |19036320;19576876320|Senior Lecturer, Institute of Nursing and Midwifery, University of Brighton, Westlain House, Village Way, Falmer, BN1 9PH Brighton, UK.|['US']            |['Brighton', 'Brighton']                                                |
-|--------------|--------------------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

You can see that the lines index 0 and 2 have been merged, same for the lines index 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from itertools import zip_longest


data = """\
text1|text2|text3|text4 text 5| text 6| text 7 text 8|
text1|text2|text12|text4 text 5| text 6| text 7| text9|text10|text3|text4 text 5| text 11| text 12 text 8|
"""

lines = tuple(line.split('|') for line in data.splitlines())
number_of_lines = len(lines)
print(f"number of lines : {number_of_lines}")
print(f"number of cells in line 1 : {len(lines[0])}")
print(f"number of cells in line 2 : {len(lines[1])}")
print(f"{lines[0]=}")
print(f"{lines[1]=}")

result = []

# we want to compare each line with each other :
for line_a_index, line_a in enumerate(lines):
    for line_b_index, line_b in enumerate(lines[line_a_index+1:]):
        assert len(line_a) >= 5, f"not enough cells ({len(line_a)}) in line {line_a_index}"
        assert len(line_b) >= 5, f"not enough cells ({len(line_b)}) in line {line_b_index}"
        assert all(isinstance(cell, str) for cell in line_a)
        assert all(isinstance(cell, str) for cell in line_b)

        if line_a[0] == line_b[0] and line_a[1] == line_b[1] and (
                line_a[5] in line_b[5] or line_a[6] in line_b[6]  # A in B
            or line_b[5] in line_a[5] or line_b[6] in line_a[6]  # B in A
        ):
            result.append(tuple(
                ((cell_a or "") + (";" if (cell_a or cell_b) else "") + (cell_b or "")) if cell_a != cell_b else cell_a
                for cell_a, cell_b in zip_longest(line_a[:5+1], line_b[:5+1])  # <-- here I truncated the lines
            ))

# I decided to have a fancy output, but I made some simplifying assumptions to make it simple
if len(result) > 1:
    raise NotImplementedError
widths = tuple(max(len(a) if a is not None else 0, len(b) if b is not None else 0, len(c) if c is not None else 0)
               for a, b, c in zip_longest(lines[0], lines[1], result[0]))
length = max(len(lines[0]), len(lines[1]), len(result[0]))
for line in (lines[0], lines[1], result[0]):
    for index, cell in zip_longest(range(length), line):
        if cell:
            print(cell.ljust(widths[index]), end='|')
    print("", end='\n')  # explicit newline

original_expected_output = "text1|text2|text3;text12|text4;text5;text4;text5|text6;text7 text8;text6"
print(f"{original_expected_output}         <-- expected")

lenormju_expected_output = "text1|text2|text3;text12|text4 text 5| text 6| text 7 text 8; text 7"
print(f"{lenormju_expected_output}             <-- fixed")
```

output

```
number of lines : 2
number of cells in line 1 : 7
number of cells in line 2 : 13
lines[0]=['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4 text 5', ' text 6', ' text 7 text 8', '']
lines[1]=['text1', 'text2', 'text12', 'text4 text 5', ' text 6', ' text 7', ' text9', 'text10', 'text3', 'text4 text 5', ' text 11', ' text 12 text 8', '']
text1|text2|text3       |text4 text 5| text 6| text 7 text 8        |
text1|text2|text12      |text4 text 5| text 6| text 7               | text9|text10|text3|text4 text 5| text 11| text 12 text 8|
text1|text2|text3;text12|text4 text 5| text 6| text 7 text 8; text 7|
text1|text2|text3;text12|text4;text5;text4;text5|text6;text7 text8;text6         <-- expected
text1|text2|text3;text12|text4 text 5| text 6| text 7 text 8; text 7             <-- fixed
```

**EDIT**:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from itertools import zip_longest


data = """\
text1|text2|text3|text4 text 5| text 6| text 7 text 8|
text1|text2|text12|text4 text 5| text 6| text 7| text9|text10|text3|text4 text 5| text 11| text 12 text 8|
"""


@dataclass
class Match:  # a convenient way to store the solutions
    line_a_index: int
    line_b_index: int
    line_result: tuple


lines = tuple(line.split('|') for line in data.splitlines())

results = []
for line_a_index, line_a in enumerate(lines):
    for line_b_index, line_b in enumerate(lines[line_a_index+1:], line_a_index+1):
        assert len(line_a) >= 5, f"not enough cells ({len(line_a)}) in line {line_a_index}"
        assert len(line_b) >= 5, f"not enough cells ({len(line_b)}) in line {line_b_index}"
        assert all(isinstance(cell, str) for cell in line_a)
        assert all(isinstance(cell, str) for cell in line_b)

        if line_a[0] == line_b[0] and line_a[1] == line_b[1] and (
                line_a[5] in line_b[5] or line_a[6] in line_b[6]  # A in B
            or line_b[5] in line_a[5] or line_b[6] in line_a[6]  # B in A
        ):
            line_result = tuple(
                ((cell_a or "") + (";" if (cell_a or cell_b) else "") + (cell_b or "")) if cell_a != cell_b else cell_a
                for cell_a, cell_b in zip_longest(line_a[:5+1], line_b[:5+1])  # <-- here I truncated the lines
            )
            results.append(Match(line_a_index=line_a_index, line_b_index=line_b_index, line_result=line_result))

# simple output of the solution
for result in results:
    print(f"line n°{result.line_a_index} matches with n°{result.line_b_index} : {result.line_result}")
```

```
line n°0 matches with n°1 : ('text1', 'text2', 'text3;text12', 'text4 text 5', ' text 6', ' text 7 text 8; text 7')
```

Comment: thank you, it is indeed fancy. It gives 3 rows as output: 2 those that were compared and 1 concatenated. How/where can one change a code so it gives only row which gets concatenated OR in case if they are not concatenated just 2 of them. So it shouldn’t be 3 rows in any case - either 1 concatenated or if expression doesn’t hold true - each row separately. Also how do you start the code from file not from data = """ string"""? When I do from file, I see IndexError: list index out of range at for a, b, c in zip_longest(lines[0], lines[1], result[0])) position

Comment: also if I add more lines even in data = """ string""", it gives NotImplementedError at raise NotImplementedError. I am supposed to have many lines

Comment: You can remove the `print`s you don't want. You did not ask for a fancy output, but I thought it would be more clear that way to present the different solutions, so I made one **specifically for your example case of 2 lines**, and added a check to make sure it would not run on more. Just remove everything under the `I decided to have a fancy output ...` comment and it will run fine.

Comment: My goal was to show that the expected output you provided seems incorrect to me, it does not match the description of the problem you gave. So I wanted to hightlight visually the differences, so I used a fancy formatting. But if you don't care about that, I have edited my answer to add a simpler way to display **ALL** the solutions.

Comment: it works but outputs only 1 common line, so if I would have many common lines in a result, how would that be? I have def combinations functions from itertools.combinations but it is pretty slow function when you make pairs. I will have millions of lines to compare. Any more efficient solution?

Comment: Please provide an extensive example which does not work with my code.

Comment: I updated the question with real data so it is more clear